# Append/Write with values of an instance

Tags: python, class, instance

So I'm new to working with classes in python, but this project Euler(q 81) I have is done using classes just to be a bit more tricky? I guess?

I can get the values of a (2n+1 * 2n+1) grid, but I can't work with them to append to another list or even write to a file.

```
def minSum(matrix):
    file = open("pleasedeargodwork.txt", "w")
    newList = []

    for x in maxtrix.grids:
        for y in x:
            newList.append(y)
            print y,
            file.write(y,)
     print newList

>>> 1 7 2 5 6 2 9 2 5
>>> TypeError: must be string or read-only character buffer, not instance
>>> <matrix.Supplies instance at 0x0240E9B8>
```

^^ I would like this last line to give me the values, rather than the instance, but how?

My matrix class looks something like this:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, grids):
       self.size = len(grids) / 2
       self.grids = [[Supplies(s) for s in row] for row in grids]

class Supplies:
    def __init__(self, supp):
        if isinstance(supp, list):
            self.value = supp[0]
```

"Matrix" is the class name, "matrix" is the filename and an argument given to my class minSum to be able to access this file.

If you need to see any more of the matrix file let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have another error when you try to write an instance to the text file but here's a way to print the values instead of the instance:

The `__repr__` method lets you define what the object looks like when it is printed.

Add a `__repr__` method to the `Supplies` class like so:

```
class Supplies:
    def __init__(self, supp):
        if isinstance(supp, list):
            self.value = supp[0]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
```

Whenever you print a `Supplies` instance, Python will print its `value` attribute instead. Note that `value` is not guaranteed to be defined in the `Supplies` class so you might want to either initialize it or check before you attempt to convert it to a string in the `__repr__` method.

**Edit**

If you want `newList` to contain the values of each `Supplies` instance you could just append the value instead of the instance:

```
newList.append(y.value)
```

instead of:

```
newList.append(y)
```

Comment: Hi there, Repr works for getting it to print the values to the console, but if I try to add or subtract with those values I get the error:

unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'instance' when I try:


    `newList = []

    for x in maxtrix.grids:


        for y in x:


            newList.append(y)`

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit that code for some reason, this reply box is super hard to work with.

    `values = 0

    for x in maxtrix.grids:
        for y in x:
            values += y`

Comment: @BlueEden can you just append `y.value` to newList? or does the `Supplies` class serve a purpose other than to hold values?

Comment: \@EngineerCamp One of my friends took a look at my code and fixed the way the structure of Supplies class was setup, thanks heaps for your help though!